# Facebook account hacked, what to do?

Tags: facebook, passwords, hacked

Someone has hacked my Facebook account and changed the password and I couldn't reset it following the regular steps.

Few days later, Facebook let me log in to my account but I'm not able to change my password since I don't know the old one now. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Report it to Facebook from here - https://www.facebook.com/hacked